# model object of StorageAccounts in microsoft azure

Tags: java, azure, cloud, azure-storage-account

I have a requirement to fetch all storage accounts from my azure account and list all of their properties.
I have configured azure object and using below call to get all storageAccounts.

```
Azure azure = Azure
                        .configure()
                        .withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE)
                        .authenticate(credFile)
                        .withDefaultSubscription();                     

StorageAccounts storageAccounts  =  azure.storageAccounts();
```

I see that in com.microsoft.azure.management.storage.StorageAccounts interface there are many methods, but I am looking for a model object to fetch and list its details just like in case of aws we have com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket

My question is: which will be the model object in case of azure for the StorageAccounts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use method `.list()` to list storage accounts in your subscription. Please check SDK in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.storage). You could use the following code to get storage accounts properties.

```
 List<StorageAccount> accounts = azure.storageAccounts().list();
            for (StorageAccount sa : accounts) {
                System.out.println("Storage Account " + sa.name() + " created @ " + sa.creationTime());
            }
```

You also could check this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-sdk-java/blob/master/docs-ref-conceptual/java-sdk-manage-storage-accounts.md) to manage your storage accounts.

Comment: Thanks but I am already using the same code you mentioned but I need to fetch each detail from storage accounts , and later on from virtual machines so looking for a model which gives all data in one go.

Comment: what data you want? You could try to print sa to list all properities.

Comment: This is just an example, you could use 'sa.' to list data you want.

Comment: I actually need following data in json format:- - 
-       List of Current running and stop Virtual Machines.
- List of available storage accounts
- List of SQL Databases 
I need to collect everything about above without missing any detail.

Comment: Could I get List or you tell list of all REST APIs that I can invoke to directly get all data about these ? I could just found a REST API detail for virtual machines, but I need for storage also. Any java implementation would be helpful.

Comment: In fact, `azure.storageAccounts().list()` use this api  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167783/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-deepak-s).